# CosmosDB connector / Delete a document in a partitioned collection / wrong header attribute used by the Designer

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Using the Logic Apps CosmosDB Connector / action "Delete a document", the generated Logic Apps code uses header attribute

x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey

which leads to errors (invalid partition key).

When correction the header attribute name manually to

x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey

everything works fine.

Anybody else with similar experiences ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me with `x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey`. Below is my LA Workflow:

[image: LA Workflow]

```
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Delete_a_document": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "headers": {
                                "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "\"abc\""
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "delete",
                            "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('test')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('test')}/docs/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['id'])}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_all_documents')?['Documents']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_all_documents": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_all_documents": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "\"abc\""
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('test')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('test')}/docs"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
```